# dojo charting candlestick code examples

Tags: charts, dojo, candlestick-chart

I am learning to use dojo, and am finding the documentation very tricky to wade through.

All I am after is a basic working candlestick chart code with minimal settings/options on so that I can use that as a base to explore and build upon. something that works so I can break it apart bit by bit and learn from!

would really appreciate your time if anyone could post a couple of basic working complete candlestick chart code examples!

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should find a candlestick example in the dojo distribution under dojox/charting/tests/test_charts2d-amd.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, however the candlestick chart is shared with 8 other examples on the page and as such I cannot make a lot of sense of the code, which is why I was after just examples of basic candlestick charts with with I can then build my knowledge upon. Thank you tho for pointing it out to me :)